# Adding a custom web application to a SharePoint site

Tags: 2007, web-application, integration

Has anyone added a custom web application to a sharepoint site?

I thought it would be added as a virtual directory and then you'd specify an unmanaged path but i'm not having much luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a big fan of mixing the two, but it can be done.  My preference is to either integrate and deploy the app to SharePoint or run it on a separate web application in IIS.

The request handling process was rewritten with 2007 so there is no longer an "excluded paths" option in the Managed Paths section.  If you create a folder in the root of the web application it will run.

Comment: ill second Mikes opinion. Also consider re-using _Layouts vdir if possible with custom application pages. Any specific reasons that you need your own vdir?

Comment: Its an existing members section to a web site and provided by a third party, so we have to 'house' it within the new site without really doing anything to it.